# how can I verify that a set of 4 points have undergone an affine transformation

Tags: affinetransform

I have two images containing same object with 4 corners.
I have a correspondence for those 4 points between images.
Let us call these points as A,B,C,D .
I have (x,y) coordinates of A in image 1 and image 2 .
Similiarly , for points B,C,D .
My aim is to verify that if there exists an affine transformation that satisfies this coordinate change of these 4 points.
How should I proceed ?
It would be beneficial if there is a code in python or c so that I can quickly verify for many images.
My understanding is that a general affine transformation can be described by
x'=ax+by+c
y'=dx+ey+f
So there are six unknowns.
 
Thanks for reading.

Comment: What have you tried? This Q&A site isn't here for other people to write your code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your points are A=(x1,y1); B=(x2,y2); C=(x3;y3); D=(x4,y4) in image 1 and A'=(x1',y1'); B'=(x2',y2'); C'=(x3';y3'); D'=(x4',y4') in image 2.

You already figured out that finding the affine transformation requires you to find the six unknowns. To find them, just write down the system of linear equations and solve:

```
x1' = a x1 + b y1 + c
y1' = d x1 + e y1 + f
x2' = a x2 + b y2 + c
y2' = d x2 + e y2 + f
x3' = a x3 + b y3 + c
y3' = d x3 + e y3 + f
x4' = a x4 + b y4 + c
y4' = d x4 + e y4 + f
```

You can actually split this into two systems of linear equations:

```
x1' = a x1 + b y1 + c
x2' = a x2 + b y2 + c
x3' = a x3 + b y3 + c
x4' = a x4 + b y4 + c
```

and

```
y1' = d x1 + e y1 + f
y2' = d x2 + e y2 + f
y3' = d x3 + e y3 + f
y4' = d x4 + e y4 + f
```

Since you are only interested in whether there exists an affine transformation (but not in the values of a, b, c, d, e, f itself), you just have to determine if these two systems of linear equations have a solution or not.

The [Rouché–Capelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem) theorem tells us that a system of linear equations has a solution if and only if the [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) of the [coefficient matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_matrix) equals the rank of the [augmented matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix).

In your case, the coefficient matrix for both systems of linear equations is

```
| x1 y1 1 |
| x2 y2 1 |
| x3 y3 1 |
| x4 y4 1 |
```

The augmented matrix for the first system of linear equations is

```
| x1 y1 1 x1' |
| x2 y2 1 x2' |
| x3 y3 1 x3' |
| x4 y4 1 x4' |
```

and for the second system of linear equations it is

```
| x1 y1 1 y1' |
| x2 y2 1 y2' |
| x3 y3 1 y3' |
| x4 y4 1 y4' |
```

Now compute the ranks of these three matrices (for example with [numpy.linalg.matrix_rank](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_rank.html)) and if they are all equal, there exists an affine transformation.

Comment: thanks a lot frececroka for lucid explanation.
i will get back if I get stuck .